# Exporting reports - Quest's Spotlight on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, spotlight

I'm setting up some monitoring on a few SQL Servers. Currently our environment uses Hobbit Monitoring System, but we are probably migrating to Nagios pretty soon.

One of the DBAs recommended Spotlight to me, and it seems like a great piece of software, but here's what I'm wondering...

**Is it possible to configure Spotlight to report some of its findings to another monitoring application?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotlight Product Architect here - The answer to your question depends on how dirty you want to get your hands...

If you don't mind writing a bit of your own code, with some guidance you could extract monitored data at relatively near real-time rates from the historical repository.

Or you could wait until next year when it is likely that we will include the ability to get at collected data real time through a web service.

Answer (score 1):

I've not been able to & have been using the Quest suite for over 5 years